# Scheduling Tasks to Execute Sequentially After a Given Delay

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have a bunch of worker threads that I want to execute sequentially after a giving delay. I would like to achieve the following behaviour:

> DELAY -> Worker 1 -> DELAY -> Worker 2 - DELAY -> Worker 3 -> ...

I came up with this solution:

```
long delay = 5;
for(String value : values) {
    WorkerThread workerThread = new WorkerThread(value);
    executorService.schedule(workerThread, delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    delay = delay + 5;
}
```

where `executorService` has been created like:

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
```

Is there any other way to achieve this with `ExecutorService` in Java?

Comment: You could have a single workerthread that executes every `delay` seconds and fetches a `value` from a queue to process.

Comment: Your current solution delays the start of each worker relative to the start of scheduling, whereas your problem layout suggests a fixed delay between one worker finishing and thee next starting. Could you clarify which you really want?

Comment: @bowmore My goal is to simulate a state machine. So, I would have a fixed delay between on worker and the next starting.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your problem, I came up with another solution. Assuming values is a queue which can be changed. Here is a solution which works. I modified your WorkerThread a little and added a callback object in there. Hope this helps.

```
private final Queue<String> values = new LinkedList<>();

private final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

private void start() {
    AtomicLong delay = new AtomicLong(5);
    String value = values.poll();

    if (value != null) {
        WorkerThread workerThread = new WorkerThread(value, new OnCompleteCallback() {
            @Override
            public void complete() {
                String valueToProcessNext = values.poll();

                if (valueToProcessNext != null) {
                    executorService.schedule(new WorkerThread(valueToProcessNext, this), delay.addAndGet(5), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                }
            }
        });
        executorService.schedule(workerThread, delay.get(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}

class WorkerThread implements Runnable {

    private final String value;

    private final OnCompleteCallback callback;

    WorkerThread(String value, OnCompleteCallback callback) {
        this.value = value;
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println(value);
        } finally {
            callback.complete();
        }
    }
}

interface OnCompleteCallback {
    void complete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing comes to mind except for your solution if `ExecutorService` should be used. However you will probably find `CompletableFuture` more useful cause it provides similar behavior but with delay relative to task completion instead for start of scheduling.

```
CompletableFuture<Void> completableFuture = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
String[] values = new String[]{"a", "b", "c"};
for (String value : values) {
    completableFuture
            .thenRun(() -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }
            })
            .thenRun(() -> System.out.println(value));
}
completableFuture.get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`DelayQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html) between each worker. And decorate your workers with this class :

```
public class DelayedTask implements Runnable {

    private final Runnable task;
    private final DelayQueue<Delayed> waitQueue;
    private final DelayQueue<Delayed> followerQueue;

    public DelayedTask(Runnable task, DelayQueue<Delayed> waitQueue, DelayQueue<Delayed> followerQueue) {
        this.task = Objects.requireNonNull(task);
        this.waitQueue = Objects.requireNonNull(waitQueue);
        this.followerQueue = followerQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            waitQueue.take();
            try {
                task.run();
            } finally {
                if (followerQueue != null) {
                    followerQueue.add(new Delay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

and a simple Delayed implementation

```
class Delay implements Delayed {
    private final long nanos;

    Delay(long amount, TimeUnit unit) {
        this.nanos = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.convert(amount, unit) + System.nanoTime();
    }

    @Override
    public long getDelay(TimeUnit unit) {
        return unit.convert(nanos - System.nanoTime(), TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Delayed other) {
        return Long.compare(nanos, other.getDelay(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS));
    }
}
```

Allowing for this usage :

```
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

// ....

    DelayQueue<Delayed> currentQueue = new DelayQueue<>();
    currentQueue.add(new Delay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    for (String value : values) {
        DelayedTask delayedTask = new DelayedTask(new WorkerThread(value), currentQueue, currentQueue = new DelayQueue<>());
        executorService.submit(delayedTask);
    }
```